# Having trouble with lambda in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pygame

I was working on a Pygame project when I ran into this problem:

```
# Note: pos is the tuple that stores mouse position
self.start_on = lambda: True if pos[1] >= 100 and pos[1] <= 200 else False
print(self.start_on)
```

returns

```
<function Menu.mouseLogic.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x10346d1e0>
```

instead of True or False.

I also tried:

```
self.start_on = (lambda: True if pos[1] >= 100 and pos[1] <= 200 else False)
print(self.start_on)
```

but that returns the same thing.

How do I make it return either True or False?

(Note: this is on python 3.5)

Comment: Not relevant, but if you want to assign a lambda (an anonymous function) to a name, just use a normal `def` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to need a lambda. And you never need to write `True if X else False`. You just need

```
self.start_on = (100 <= pos[1] <= 200)
```

If you do want to use a lambda, so you can use `self.start_on` to calculate this condition later, it would be:

```
self.start_on = lambda: (100 <= pos[1] <= 200)
```

and you can print the result of it via `print(self.start_on())` because you always need parentheses to call a function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `lambda`. Just do `self.start_on = True if pos[1] >= 100 and pos[1] <= 200 else False`. Or even simpler, `self.start_on = pos[1] >= 100 and pos[1] <= 200`.

`lambda` creates an anonymous function, but it looks like you just need a value.

Answer (score 2):

You are **almost** there. Just make sure to actually run the lambda:

```
self.start_on = lambda: True if pos[1] >= 100 and pos[1] <= 200 else False
print(self.start_on()) # <-- note the () after self.start_on
```

The brackets after the lambda call the function.

You can also go a step further and simplify the lambda:

```
self.start_on = lambda: (100 <= pos[1] <= 200)
print(self.start_on())
```